# iPhone 4a shutdown shortcut

Tags: iphone, shortcuts

With a rooted android s4 I remember being able to create a quick shortcut for turning off the phone with the volume buttons (e.g. up+down+up)

If there is a any way to achieve a shutdown of a non-rooted iPhone 4s (iOs 8.3) quicker than the route of holding, holding, holding and then sliding, that info will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The only way of shutting down your iPhone without a cable connection is by holding down the power button and sliding "shut down". You can also use Assistive Touch so that you don't have to use the hardware button.

And as a reminder, mobile questions are frowned upon on this site. You should go to the SE site for Apple products, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), next time.

Comment: Thanks. Ask Different is denying my (very popular) VPN access to their site "due to spam".

Comment: @Manumit - If you continue questions like this here that will happen again.  If enough of your questions are closed and downvoted, you won't be able to ask new questions, so ask good on topic question NOT about apple mobile devices.